# Progressbar for a Flash game file

Tags: javascript, flash, progress-bar

i have a game website, and sometimes is the swf game flash file > 2mb and the browser need a time to display it. And the Flash  stay blank.

How i can make a progressbar with javascript to detect after how much time can the user play the game ( Swf file)

thank u

Answer (score 1):

JqUploader - jQuery plugin for file upload and progressbar
http://pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/

example, [Escape Room Games](http://www.2keysgames.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Flash it self :)
Check it out here

http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Loading-Screen-in-Flash

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/tween_as_preloader.htm